# javascript function does not get called

Tags: javascript

I am writing javascript code with revealing prototype pattern for the first time. I am having problems. When I call add function when user clicks add button then it shows me this error in the console.

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'add' of undefined`

How can I solve this problem?

here is my script.js code

```
$(function () {
var todo = Todo('contents');

$('.addBtn').on('click', function() {
    var name = $(this).parent().find('input[type="text"]').val();
    todo.add(name);
});

$('.contents').on('click', '.remove', function() {
    var el = $(this).parent();
    todo.remove(el);
});

$('.contents').on('click', '.update', function() {
    var dom = $(this);
    todo.addUpdateField(dom);
});

$('.contents').on('click', '.updateBtn', function() {
    var el = $(this);
    todo.update(el);
});

});
```

here is my todo.js code

```
var Todo = function(c) {
    this.contents = $('.' + c);
};

Todo.prototype = function() {
var showel = function (d) {
    this.contents.prepend(d);
},

add = function (name) {
    if(name != "") {
        var div = $('<div class="names"></div>')
        .append('<span>' + name + '</span>')
        .append("<button class='update' class='update'>Edit</button>")
        .append("<button class='remove' name='remove'>Remove</button>");
    }

    return showel(div);
},

addUpdateField = function (dom) {
    var name = dom.parent().find('span').text(),
        field = $('<input type="text" value="' + name + '" />'),
        update = $('<button class="updateBtn">Update</button>');

    dom.parent().html('').append(field).append(update);

    return;
},

update = function(el) {
    var val = el.parent().find('input').val();
    el.parent().html('<span>' + val + '</span>')
    .append('<button class="update" class="update">Edit</button>')
    .append('<button class="remove" class="remove">Remove</button>');

    return;
},

remove = function (el) {
    return el.remove();
};

return {
    add             : add,
    update          : update,
    remove          : remove,
    addUpdateField  : addUpdateField
};

}();
```

**Update**

After changing
`var todo = Todo('contents');`

to

`var todo = new Todo('contents');`

I get this error

`Object [object Object] has no method 'add'`

**update 2**

here is my on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BagmY/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to assign `Todo`'s `prototype` to a self-calling function. However, the prototype is just getting assigned to a function and not the expected return object.

Here's your working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BagmY/2/). I assigned the prototype directly to an object with your methods.

Also, JS parses from top to bottom. Therefore, define your new instance of `Todo` after you declare what `Todo` is.

This is what a self-calling function should look like:

```
Todo.prototype = (function() {

    // ...

    return {
        add: add,
        update: update,
        remove: remove,
        addUpdateField: addUpdateField
    };

})();​
```

Comment: could you elaborate your answer please?

Comment: I am using revealing prototype pattern to learn this pattern. The example you posted is a modular pattern. Secondly it does work now but when I use return showel(div) line in add method then it shows this error Cannot call method 'append' of undefined . And when I use this line in add method return this.contents.prepend(div); then it works. Why am I getting this error when I do it the first way and how can I make it work while sticking to revealing prototype pattern?

Comment: The fiddle doesn't use any specific pattern. The example above is the [revealing module pattern](http://www.klauskomenda.com/code/javascript-programming-patterns/#revealing). I'm not sure what your problem is--try recreating it in a fiddle.

Answer (score 3):

You're not properly constructing your object, so it does not have any of the prototypes:

`var todo = Todo('contents');`

should be:

`var todo = new Todo('contents');`

Here is an [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5385372/using-new-in-constructors-john-resigs-35) explaining what is happening when you forget the `new`.

Edit: the way you are defining your prototype functions is messing up the context (what `this` points to). Try a pattern like this instead:

```
Todo.prototype = {
    method1: function () { ... },
    method2: function () { ... }
};
```

fixed fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/BagmY/3/

Comment: Now it shows this error `Object [object Object] has no method 'add' `

Comment: Could you tell me why am I getting above error i.e. this one `Object [object Object] has no method 'add'`

Comment: @al0neevenings i honestly don't know why it wouldnt work after adding the `new`, the code you posted should work. perhaps another member will be able to spot the problem.

Comment: I have added jsfiddle link. could you please modify my code to make it work? thanks

Comment: I am using revealing prototype pattern to learn this pattern. The example you posted is a modular pattern. Secondly it does work now but when I use `return showel(div)` line in add method then it shows this error `Cannot call method 'append' of undefined `. And when I use this line in add method `return this.contents.prepend(div);` then it works. Why am I getting this error when I do it the first way and how can I make it work while sticking to revealing prototype pattern?